# command for checking Apache configuration

Tags: configuration, apache2

I'm looking for a command that checks the validity of the config files in Apache server on both Debian and RHEL distros.  I need to do this prior to restart, so there will be no downtime.

Answer (score 430, accepted):

Check: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html

```
apachectl configtest
```

Comment: I am getting this message running the above command `AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

Comment: Add a line "ServerName whateveryoulike" to your apache config. Replace whateveryoulike with what ever you like to name your server.

Comment: might require sudo ?

Comment: Check everything apache with helpful suggestions ```curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/richardforth/apache2buddy/master/apache2buddy.pl | perl```

Answer (score 58):

Another way is `httpd -t`. Therefore, it's available in Windows-version of Apache. Check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/httpd.html

Comment: Oddly, on Ubuntu, when I run `apachectl configtest` I get `Syntax OK`, but when I run `apache2 -t` I get `AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (among other errors)

Comment: @ButtleButkus but the server when you systemctl restart apache2 is ok right?

Answer (score 14):

The Apache config test (`apachectl configtest`, or its equivalents) only tests the config file (and the files it recursively includes) for valid syntax. However, the original question asked for preventing downtime. Even when `apachectl configtest` does not return an error, an actual restart may still fail, causing downtime.

Common causes for such failures include missing or inaccessible SSL certificates, missing directories for log files or a missing website root directory. Often, such errors are caused by removing a vhost's directory without removing the vhost Apache config file. It is highly recommended to use a tool like puppet or ansible to prevent such inconsistencies.

Seeing that this question is the number one hit when googling "apache config lint" I thought I'd mention this little detail...

Comment: Is there a way to test for common causes of failure per above?

Comment: That would require a script, that parses the apache config and implements the missing checks. I'm not aware of any freely available scripts that does so.

Comment: I have written such a script.  If I took the time to put it on github, would anyone use it?  It specifically checks SSL configurations, that the files are in the correct location and that the modulos match using openssl, among other things.

Comment: I would! Putting it on github definitely is a bonus.

Comment: @JamesM.Lay I hope you post the link to it on github... save many people from writing such scripts again and again.

Comment: @Jakke PRs are welcome. https://github.com/jlmgtech/apache-config-auditor

Comment: @BertD Idk if you still need it, but see my response to Jakke above

Comment: @JamesM.Lay Thank you very much for that link. I'm good with PHP / bash but JS is a little outside my comfort zone... so I'm not sure I could contribute. I'll play around with it this weekend and see where I get with it.

Comment: @Jakke I would have chosen a different option, but node had the best apache config parser library.  Perhaps such a tool would be best written in Rust or the likes.

Comment: FYI, `apachectl configtest` caught the fact my SSL certificate was missing (I mis-typed the directory). I suspect newer versions of apache are better about catching errors.

Answer (score 8):

`apachectl configtest` is the correct answer.
Unfortunately I've got a windows installation where apachectl is missing.
Here calling `httpd` also helps.

Answer (score 5):

What I usually do is

```
apache2ctl -t && apache2ctl graceful
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you explained why this works.

Comment: I'll hazard a guess.  The "-t" runs a syntax test for configuration files only.  If that fails, the && prevents the next command from running.  The next command, 'apache2ctl graceful' will restart the httpd service in a way that won't disconnect existing connections (hence, graceful).

Answer (score 1):

There is always a **good** idea to take a look at the error logs.

```
less /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

-- Paul

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/536769)

Answer (score 0):

I have actually tried before:

> apachectl configtest

We can actually see the status code to know the error:

> /etc/init.d/apache2 restart; systemctl status apache2.service
>
> ● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-05-30 17:16:45 +08; 41ms ago
> Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
> Process: 168391 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
> CPU: 67ms
>
> May 30 17:16:45 kali systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
> May 30 17:16:45 kali apachectl[168394]: AH00526: **Syntax error on line
> 13 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/security2.conf**